# Linq Edit ListView

Tags: asp.net, linq, listview

im trying to edit a field using code instead of the wizard. im not entirely sure if the code i have is correct to update the field. here is the code i have to edit the field:

```
 Protected Sub ListView1_ItemEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewEditEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemEditing
    ListView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    ListView1.DataBind()
End Sub

Protected Sub ListView1_ItemUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemUpdating
    Dim profile = Request.QueryString("Profile")
    Dim postid As Label = DirectCast(ListView1.EditItem.FindControl("postId"), Label)
    Dim textbox As TextBox = DirectCast(ListView1.EditItem.FindControl("EditPostTxt"), TextBox)
    Dim getComment = (From p In db.Posts Where p.PostId = New Guid(postid.Text)).Single

    getComment.Post = cc.reverseExchangeSmilies(textbox.Text)
    db.SubmitChanges()

    ListView1.EditIndex = -1
    cc.LoadComments(profile, ListView1)
End Sub
```

when ever i try to ether update or cancel the post because the post contains html i get the following error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client
```

i was wondering if before it updated the post it could use the reverseExchangeSmilies to turn them back in to smiles instead of there html  or maybe allow html to be used at this point.

aspx page:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <div id="header">

                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="UserPageLik" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"Default.aspx?Profile=" + Eval("ProfileId") %>'> <%# Eval("fullname")%> </asp:HyperLink><br />
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="leftcolumn">
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("DisaplyPictureSmall") %>' /></div>
                                        <div id="content">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Post") %>'></asp:Label><br />
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="footer">
                                            <%# Eval("Date")%><br />
                                            <asp:linkbutton id="linkbutton1" runat="server" CommandName="del" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PostId") %>' forecolor="red" text="Delete" onclientclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" />
                                             <asp:linkbutton id="linkbutton2" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PostId") %>' forecolor="red" text="Edit" />
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                    <EditItemTemplate>
                                    <div id="header">
                                        <asp:Label ID="postId" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PostId") %>'></asp:Label>
                                            <asp:HyperLink ID="UserPageLik" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"Default.aspx?Profile=" + Eval("ProfileId") %>'> <%# Eval("fullname")%> </asp:HyperLink><br />
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="leftcolumn">
                                            <asp:ImageButton ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("DisaplyPictureSmall") %>' /></div>
                                        <div id="content">
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="EditPostTxt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Post") %>' Width="100%" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                                        </div>
                                        <div id="footer">
                                            <%# Eval("Date")%><br />
                                             <asp:linkbutton id="SaveEditBut" runat="server" CommandName="Update" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PostId") %>' forecolor="red" text="Update" />
                                             <asp:linkbutton id="Linkbutton3" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("PostId") %>' forecolor="red" text="Cancel" />
                                        </div>
                                        <br />
                                    </EditItemTemplate>
                                </asp:ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework is preventing you from posting html code as a security measure. This can be turned off for the current page by adding a page directive.

```
<%@ Page validateRequest="false" %>
```

The other option is to use javascript on the client side to change '<' to < and '>' to > and '&' to & before posting. Then on the server side you could decode the html before writing it to the screen.

```
function encodeValue(element_id) 
{   
    var elem = document.getElementById(element_id);
    var html = elem.value;
    html= html.replace(/&/gi,"&amp;");
    html= html.replace(/</gi,"&lt;");
    html= html.replace(/>/gi,"&gt;");
    elem.value = html;
}
```

Comment: I don't really want to turn off the security measure as i don't want users to be able to post html in there posts. i have a method that can turn all the html back to there original state i.e from <img src="smile.jpg"> to :) but i am unaware where to put this method.

Comment: @Houlahan - is the method to convert the html to plain text smilies in javascript? If so, it should be called in the onsubmit event of the form.

Comment: @Houlahan - the solution has to be client side, because the validation is going to stop processing before you get a chance to do it. I assume what you are doing is getting some text like "Hi have a nice day :)" and then you replace the ':)' with '<img src="smile.jpg">' and then store that in the database? And when they edit the value, the html ends up in the edit box? If that's the case, I would either not store the html, but store the raw text as entered and convert to html when displaying. Or reverse the html before populating the field for editing the content.

Comment: yes that is exactly what im doing :) how would i use the JavaScript method that you have provided? i have edited my post above to show my listview. thanks

Comment: @Houlahan - In your scenario, what I would recommend doing is leaving the text as it was input and storing the plain text. Then as part of the display code, process the plain text replacing any content you want with related HTML. This becomes a display concern and simplifies your workflow.